# React Custom component is not getting rendered as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jsx

I am expecting text : SMALL Medium, Big  rendered on screen , but its not getting rendered

```
 function Box(prop){
        const ele = <div className={prop.cn}>

                    </div>

        return ele
      }

      const ele = <div className="container">
                       <Box cn='small'>SMALL</Box>
                       <Box cn='medium'>Medium</Box>
                       <Box cn='medium'>BIG</Box>
                  </div>

      ReactDOM.render(ele, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Babel is compiling this JSX to this the picture below, I don't know why children array is not getting populated in BOX function. plz help

[image]

Comment: you defined const ele twice? can you provide the code for full component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use :

```
function Box(prop){
    const ele = <div className={prop.cn}>
                     {prop.children} 
                </div>

    return ele
  }
```

Comment: thanks       function Box(prop){
        console.log(prop)
        const ele = <div className={prop.cn} children={prop.children}>
                    </div>

        return ele
      }  this worked

Comment: you are welcome ,[this is how you accept an answer on stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

You should use **children** prop for provide Box element content to the div element inside it:

```
function Box({cn, children}){
  const ele = <div className={cn}>
                 {children} 
              </div>
  return ele
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was under the assumption that children will automatically put inside div tag

Comment: When you think about any development tools, you should remember, that any tools provide you a flexibility in dessision, how you can make something by many different ways. For example, you can declare Box as something like this:
const Box({className, value}) => <div {...{className}}>{value}</div>
so, as you see, in this case, content provided as Box children took to some problems )
"Explicit is better than implicit" - remember that rule and always use it, when analyze some tools